# How to rewrite this postgres constraint to be more in line with django 2.2?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-migration, check-constraints

THis is the raw query that I write for postgres for the check constraint

```
   ALTER TABLE rea_asplinkage ADD CONSTRAINT asp_sub_project_positive_integer
        CHECK (
            jsonb_typeof(linkage-> 'root' -> 'in_sub_project') is not distinct from 'number'
        and (linkage->'root'->>'in_sub_project')::numeric % 1 = 0
        and (linkage->'root'->>'in_sub_project')::numeric > 0
        );
```

And the way I create the migration is this way

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.10 on 2020-05-16 12:59

from django.db import connection, migrations



class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("rea", "0029_asplinkage")]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="""
            ALTER TABLE rea_asplinkage ADD CONSTRAINT asp_sub_project_positive_integer
            CHECK (
                jsonb_typeof(linkage-> 'root' -> 'in_sub_project') is not distinct from 'number'
            and (linkage->'root'->>'in_sub_project')::numeric % 1 = 0
            and (linkage->'root'->>'in_sub_project')::numeric > 0
            );
            """,
            reverse_sql="""
                ALTER TABLE rea_asplinkage DROP CONSTRAINT "asp_sub_project_positive_integer";
            """,
        )
    ]
```

And this works.

But this means that my original model does not show the constraint in the `class Meta` of the ASPLinkage model

```
class ASPLinkage(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel, PersonStampedModel, OrganizationOwnedModel):
    linkage = JSONField(default=default_linkage_for_asp)

    objects = OrganizationOwnedSoftDeletableManager()
```

I have tried `ExpressionWrapper` and `RawSQL` in creating the constraints inside the class Meta, but it still doesn't work.

For reference, I have looked at the examples found in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/constraints/models.py#L12

I have also looked at Separate Database and State migration via https://realpython.com/create-django-index-without-downtime/#when-django-generates-a-new-migration

But I still cannot get it to work

So is this even possible?

### Update

Let me write a summary of my question for better readability.

1. I want to write constraints on a JSONField.
2. I can do that directly on the Postgres
3. Therefore I can do it using raw sql in the migration file
4. But I cannot do the equivalent using Django model meta / CheckConstraint which usually is how anyone does it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/
5. So how do I rewrite this raw sql to produce constraint on a jsonfield in postgres but in the Django way?

Comment: Are you just using this field to store an integer? If so can you use a `models.PositiveIntegerField` instead?

Comment: because i need to cater for semi-structured data, i chose jsonb. therefore, jsonb is a hard limit. But at the same time, i want to cater for as much data integrity as possible at the database level. so my answer to your question is NO. it's not just to store 1 field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve that on Django 2.2 [you'll need to register two new `JSONField` transforms/lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-lookups/#a-simple-transformer-example) since [support for conditional expressions was only added in the upcoming 3.1 release](https://github.com/django/django/commit/e9a0e1d4f6ecfc4227acff74e1f56f288a0b30aa).

You'll first want to register lookups for `JSONField` key accesses

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.lookups import Lookup
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import (
    KeyTransform, KeyTransformTextLookupMixin
)

@KeyTransform.register_lookup
class KeyTransformIsInteger(KeyTransformTextLookupMixin, Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'is_int'
    prepare_rhs = False

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        key_expr = KeyTransform(
            self.lhs.key_name, *self.lhs.source_expressions, **self.lhs.extra
        )
        key_sql, key_params = self.process_lhs(
            compiler, connection, lhs=key_expr
        )
        lhs_sql, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        sql = "(jsonb_typeof(%s) = %%s AND mod(%s::numeric, %%s) = %%s) IS %s" % (
            key_sql, lhs_sql, rhs_sql
        )
        params = [
            *key_params, 'number',
            *lhs_params, 1, 0,
            *rhs_params,
        ]
        return sql, params

@KeyTransform.register_lookup
class KeyTransformIntegerGt(KeyTransformTextLookupMixin, Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'int_gt'
    prepare_rhs = False

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs_sql, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        sql = "%s::int > %s" % (lhs_sql, rhs_sql)
        params = [*lhs_params, *rhs_params]
        return sql, params
```

Once this is done you should be able to define your constraint like

```py
CheckConstraint(
    check=Q(
        linkage__root__in_sub_project__is_int=True,
        linkage__root__in_sub_project__int_gt=0,
    ),
    name='asp_sub_project_positive_integer',
)
```

Once you're on Django 3.1 you should be able to pass a `RawSQL` directly to `CheckConstraint.check` as long as it has an `output_field = models.BooleanField()`.

```py
RawSQL("""
   jsonb_typeof(linkage-> 'root' -> 'in_sub_project') is not distinct from 'number'
   and (linkage->'root'->>'in_sub_project')::numeric % 1 = 0
   and (linkage->'root'->>'in_sub_project')::numeric > 0
""",
    output_field=models.BooleanField()
)
```

Comment: > return sql % (lhs, lhs, rhs), params the lhs and rhs are undefined here. Can help?

Comment: You can take a look at my 2ndtry in https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/60149d5ab4bad1817fc33315dc11b300 after I try to narrow down the errors

Comment: I adjusted the answer to address the missing variable name references and include the lhs params twice.

Comment: thanks but still doesn't work there's some issue with the % sign i think. please check my 3rd try. Note I already placed the %% https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/60149d5ab4bad1817fc33315dc11b300#file-3rdtry-py

Comment: I'll award the bounty even tho this answer hasn't quite solved it yet. I'll mark it as correct when it does solve. Thank you

Comment: Adjusted the answer with lookups tested against Django 2.2 instead of pseudo code.

Comment: Wow! It works. I see that you're at 2950 so I will give you another 50 pts to help you get to a nice round 3k.

Comment: Erm it's a bit weird minimum is 200 now and I cannot award immediately. So i guess you have to wait. ‍♂️ By the way, are you available to help teach a man how to fish? ie teach me how you get debug your own key transform until it works? Because I use ipdb i still cannot reverse engineer how you did this. And I foresee I have more such constraints to write and I cannot wait till Django 3.2 We can discuss monetary compensation if you prefer tobe paid by $ rather than pts for teaching a Django beginner

Comment: Thanks for your kind offer @KimStacks but I'm not taking freelance work at the moment and I usually prefer to spend my time contributing to Django itself when possible. I suggest you have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGF-0csOjPw and go through the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-lookups/ to learn more about it. In the end you want `as_sql` to return something you'd be able to pass to `cursor.execute`, I had to use `mod` over `%` because the latter conflicted with string formatting.

Comment: I respect that. Thank you Simon nevertheless 

Comment: Bounty Awarded. Thank you